# SQL Server 2012 Error: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 1

Tags: sql

I have been having some series issues with my webserver machine running MS SQL Server 2012 64-Bit Standard. I keep getting this error:

02/23/2013 21:49:17,spid54,Unknown,There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
02/23/2013 21:49:17,spid54,Unknown,Error: 701 Severity: 17 State: 130.

which when I read the MS SQL log file, this issue always starts with this entry:

02/23/2013 21:49:16,spid57,Unknown,Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 1

**System Specs**: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, 5GB RAM, 2 x Intel Xeon Dual-Core

Approximately every 5 days, SQL Server crashes due to this memory error. I have tried upgrading to Cumulative Update 5 which supposedly includes a hotfix for this memory error. I've tried setting the max memory to 2600mb (because this machine is also my webserver). I can't figure out what is causing this error or why MS SQL won't reset itself if the error occurs -- it will literally keep trying to run queries until the server's memory is maxed out. Any ideas would be wonderful.

Comment: Is it the same query (perhaps with different parameters) that causes the error?

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL Server, does it log queries automatically or is there a way to log these so I can look for the query that might be causing this?

Comment: Where is the sql coming from? are you using entity framwork, Nhibernate, Llblgen, Writing it yourself?
Look at using the Sql Profiler to caputer the activity on  your Sql.  I'm guessing, that a badly written query or poorly indexed database is causing the problem.

Comment: ASP using ODBC connection to SQL Server. All of the SQL is written by me. There are multiple select queries per page performing product lookups (each record contains the SKU #, description, price, etc.). Would an index be necessary? I have SQL Profiler logging every query and I'm waiting for it to happen again.

Comment: Depends on how much data is in the tables referenced by the query. But if you capture the query in profiler and then run that query "by hand" you should see how long it takes and how much data it returns. If you look at the query plan you can see how hard it hits the database.  Have you ruled out bad memory in the machine?

Comment: The maximum allowed amount of returned records is 500 which is paged through 10, 20, 30, or 50 records at a time. Most queries return only 1 or 2 records. My largest table has almost a million records but with only 4 columns: Manufacturer, SKU, Description, Price. Should this be indexed? This is where the slowest queries come from. My thoughts were about the memory originally -- tested OK and has never been an issue previously.

Comment: Yes, If you have 1 million records it should be indexed, beyond the primary key index. How long does it take to return 1 or 2 records, should be milliseconds. How are you doing the restriction to 500 records in the query or by not reading anymore when you get to that number?

Comment: The ranges of 500 records are manually pre-defined by me every time there is a major update (the majority of the db changes are price and availability updates) and use the select "BETWEEN" operator. It takes milliseconds to return records out of the million records, but sometimes it takes 1 to 2 seconds to return 500 records using the "BETWEEN" operator. I've never used an index before with SQL Server. Will the index automatically update if I make a major change to the table?

Answer (score 0):

When ran into error 701, check your SQL log(Object explorer > Management > Sql server log), you should find these kind of thing:

```
2014-01-14 14:19:42.25 spid97
CACHESTORE_SQLCP (Total)
VM Reserved = 0 KB
......
SinglePage Allocator = xxx KB
Multipage Allocator = 0 KB ......
```

Above the log pasted by you.
701 log is caused when page is applied for. If *xxx* is enough huge, **CACHESTORE_SQLCP**, this Memory Clerk tied up too much. 
You should check your client.
SQL Server cannot resolve this kind of error. You should improve the behavior of your application.

Have a try SqlDiag, path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\Sqldiag.exe